# How to implement Photoeditor in flutter

Tags: android, image, flutter, dart, editor

How to implement a photo editing feature in the Flutter app? I have attached a screenshot of the existing app in the PlayStore. In that app few pngs are available and when the user clicks on png that png gets placed on the image and there is a save button which saves the image with a png placed above it. Can anyone help me with this how to proceed and what are the packages I have to use? Can anyone explain it in detail?

[image]

[image]